# Rivest - Time Memory Tradeoff Using Distinguished Points

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, reference-request

A while ago, [Hellman introduced](https://ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/36.pdf) a time-memory tradeoff for chosen plaintext attack on block ciphers.

There is an innovation due Rivest using a concept of 'distinguished points'. I am looking for the original reference to Rivest's contribution. All references I have found to Rivest point me to the book

D. Denning, Cryptography and Data Security , p. 100, Addison-Wesley, 1982

which gives only a few sentence description of Rivest's idea and no citation to any paper of Rivest on this topic.

Comment: It may be a lost case :`Remark: the idea of using distinguished points in Hellman's tradeoff was noted earlier by Rivest [Den82, p.100], although no further reference in public literature is
known`  from [On the Time-Memory Tradeoff Between Exhaustive
Key Search and Table Precomputation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.9614&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Maybe Rivest can answer this?

Comment: Oh well... at least the ideas are floating around in other papers